# paypal javascript drop drop down menu check box

Tags: javascript, paypal

How can I make this PHP function into a JavaScript using the same algorithm or better?

```
error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
if($_GET['text008']=="1br")
{   $typeservice=119;
    if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }

}



if($_GET['text008']=="2br")
{
    $typeservice=139;
    if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }

}
if($_GET['text008']=="3br")
{
    $typeservice=159;
    if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }

}
if($_GET['text008']=="4br")
{
    $typeservice=189;
    if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }

}
if($_GET['text008']=="5br")
{
    $typeservice=219;
        if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }

}
if($_GET['text008']=="6br")
{
    $typeservice=249;
    if(isset($_GET['extras']))
    foreach ($_GET['extras'] as $k){   
    $total +=$k;
    } 
    echo "Service: $" . $typeservice . "<br/>" . "Extra Fees: $" .$total . "<br/>";

    echo "Service w/ Extra Fee: $" . $balyo=$typeservice + $total;

    if(isset($_GET['freq']))
    {
        if($_GET['freq']=="O")
        {
            echo "<br/>Once";
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;     
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="M")
        {   
            echo "<br/>Monthly";    
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .10);
            echo "<br/>Discount:$ " . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
        if($_GET['freq']=="BW")
        {
            echo "<br/>Bi-Weekly";  
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }
        if($_GET['freq']=="W")
        {
            echo "<br/>Weekly"; 
            $lahat = $balyo - ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/>Discount: $" . ($balyo * .15);
            echo "<br/> Total: $" . $lahat;             
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know any JavaScript? What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Scott, im not really familiar with javascript i need to make a javascript code that functions the same as as that php code

Comment: Welcome to SO, Dave. I thought that may be the case, unfortunately this site is not for requesting other people to code for you. If you don't know JavaScript then you will need to learn it, or seek your solution elsewhere. This site can only provide help where you have an understanding of the problem, and have attempted to solve it yourself. Please see the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I responded on Facebook with an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BVWSR/4/) but thought I would post here just in case.  It was a jsFiddle setting combined with missing curly braces in the if statements and setting the amount as an integer instead of a string.

```
function CalculateOrder(form)
{   
    //sample lang to sir ng javascript pero ito mismo na yung code.
    //naka comment sa html ung code sa php 
    if(form.text008.value == "1br")
    {
        form.amount.value ="119.00";
    }

    if(form.text008.value == "1br" && form.extrass.checked ==true)
    {
        form.amount.value = "139";
    }
}
```

Comment: There it is thanks Scott!